# Tags for language pairs

Tags: discussion, tags, languages

Is it common or appropriate to create a tag for finding equivalent functions between two languages, and what format should be used for such tags?

For instance, I have a question (and have seen questions on this) about porting from Matlab code to R.  A short tag would be `Matlab2R`, which, frankly, looks dumb.  `Convert-Matlab-to-R` seems more apropos, but verbose.  Perhaps `rewrite-matlab-r`?

---

Update: I accepted the answer for two reasons.  The first is that for less common language pairs on SO, introducing new tags is a bad idea: the number of subscribers will be low.  It's best to use both of the languages.  The second reason is more general: even for common pairs, such as C++ and Java, it's better to focus on the intended functionality, with an example drawn from the original language.  In that case, it's probably best to just focus on the targeted language than the original language.  With a larger user base, the targeted language won't often lack for people who grasp the idea.  So, it's better to use the limited tags for specific functionality.

Comment: Always keep in mind to keep such questions specific, SO is not a Code-Translation-Service.

Comment: @PaddedCell Certainly.  I have in mind a case like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599146/testing-if-rows-of-a-matrix-or-data-frame-are-sorted-in-r).  I probably erred in mentioning translation, as this is more akin to "Does an equivalent function exist?"

Comment: Hmm, out of curiosity, why is a question about whether to create new tags a bad question?  Am I missing something?  I now believe it's bad to create the new tags, but am not sure how I went astray in asking about that.  C'est la vie.

Comment: [Downvotes on Meta do not only mean that is is a bad question, they can also indicate disagreement.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @PaddedCell Thanks!  In this case the downvotes are definitely educational.  :)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just tag them [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) and [r](/questions/tagged/r). That's how people will naturally search for those questions.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: This is the simpler way, and the correct one, IMO. I doubt there are users who are looking for questions about converting Matlab to R; still who can answer to those questions are users who know both Matlab and R.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you're right.  The #s of followers for each are rather small after all.